# Show value if months equals current month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with monthly targets per product, and in another sheet I want to reference this and only show the target of the current month.

```
            June 2022   July 2022   August 2022
Product 1   50          60          70
Product 2   20          40          60
```

The formula I tried is:

```
=IF(MONTH(A1)=MONTH(targets!$B$1:$D$1), targets!B2:D2, "")
```

Where A1 has `=TODAY()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(B2:D3,MONTH(B1:D1)=MONTH(F1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
=index(B2:D3,0,match(G1,B1:D1))
```

But exact match might be safer

```
=index(B2:D3,0,match(eomonth(G1,-1)+1,B1:D1,0))
```

in case the required month is missing.

[image]